# Vulnerability scanner connecting to remote registry service is failing

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, uac

I am trying to perform full vulnerability scans against all of my corporate PCs, servers and laptops. However, I'm unable to read/connect to the target registry despite the 'Remote Registry' service being started, and being part of the Local Administrator group for all.

In researching this issue, it appears that the UAC comes into play and prevents the scanner from accessing the registry.  Are there any other workarounds other than:

1. Join the machines to a domain and then use domain administrator credentials
2. Disable User Account Control (UAC) remote restrictions on the machines

Comment: I interpolate that you are operating in a Windows ecosystem. What kind of vulnerability scanner are you running? It sounds like it's not a pure network scanner.

Comment: Yes, Windows Operating system - I'm using Nessus to do the full vulnerability scanning.